# Error in .zshrc file

Tags: zsh, kubuntu

I've just installed last kubuntu and zsh shell, not for first time by the way. But in this time it shows some configuration option (perhaps it occurs problem), I chose something and quit. Then as usually i've change zshrc file and zhystory with my old, but .zshrc won't work. An error occures in first possible line (in this case it is a comment, but i've change it and error in first character too):

```
➜  ~  zsh
/home/akder/.zshrc:1: command not found: #
```

So it load nothing. I install it with `sudo apt-get install zsh`, there is no error. I've tried to reinstall it, but has the same result.

```
zsh --version
zsh 5.0.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Could you give the first lines of your .zshrc file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4093259 .zshrc

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're setting `histchars` (or `HISTCHARS`) in some other zsh configuration file that is read before `~/.zshrc`: `/etc/zsh/zshenv`, `~/.zshenv` or `/etc/zsh/zshrc`. Fix: don't do that.

Comment: I checked all files in `/etc/zsh/` `zshenv, zprofile, zshrc, zlogin` and all that files in `home` there is no `HISTCHARS`. But now I see that `.zprofile` works and i can use it instead `.zshrc`

Comment: It works but now it dont, even in `/etc/zsh/.zshrc` file

Comment: I reinstalled it, removed '/etc/zsh/', thin in install menu check `0` (it was all about creating `zshrc` file) change i with my content and now it works, i mean the error is still there, but all other functions like autocomp works file.